# Why is audioClip lip sync off in this Unity try?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud text-to-speech to get a live audioClip. The goal is to move the lips y scale of a simple transform attached to a body. However, the timing of the lips during clip playback seems off. Is there any way to correct this? Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SyncMouthToAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float scaleYMin = 0.01f;
    const float scaleYMax = 0.05f;

    TextToSpeechVoice voice = null;

    AudioSource audioSource = null;
    float[] clipData = null;

    const float updateStep = 0.1f;
    float detectedLoudnessMin = Mathf.Infinity;
    float detectedLoudnessMax = 0f;

    const float updateSeconds = 0.096f;
    float updateTime = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        voice = GetComponentInParent<TextToSpeechVoice>();
        voice.onStarts += OnVoiceStarts;
        voice.onEnds += OnVoiceEnds;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        updateTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (updateTime >= updateSeconds)
        {
            updateTime = 0f;
            CheckLoudness();
        }
    }

    void CheckLoudness()
    {
        float loudness = 0f;
        if (audioSource != null && audioSource.isPlaying && audioSource.timeSamples > 0)
        {
            audioSource.clip.GetData(clipData, audioSource.timeSamples);
            foreach (var sample in clipData)
            {
                loudness += Mathf.Abs(sample);
            }

            if      (loudness < detectedLoudnessMin) { detectedLoudnessMin = loudness; }
            else if (loudness > detectedLoudnessMax) { detectedLoudnessMax = loudness; }
        }

        SetScaleByLoudness(loudness);
    }

    void SetScaleByLoudness(float loudness)
    {
        const float visibilityMultiplier = 15f;
        float scaleY = scaleYMin;

        bool detectedLoudness = loudness > 0f && detectedLoudnessMin < Mathf.Infinity &&
            detectedLoudnessMax > 0f && detectedLoudnessMin < detectedLoudnessMax;
        if (detectedLoudness)
        {
            float range = detectedLoudnessMax - detectedLoudnessMin;
            float threshold = detectedLoudnessMin + range * 0.3f;
            bool loudnessIsRelevantEnough = loudness >= threshold;
            if (loudnessIsRelevantEnough)
            {
                float scaleRange = scaleYMax - scaleYMin;
                float loudnessRange = detectedLoudnessMax - detectedLoudnessMin;

                float scaleToLoudnessRatio = scaleRange / loudnessRange;

                scaleY = scaleYMin + (loudness - detectedLoudnessMin) * scaleToLoudnessRatio * scaleYMax * visibilityMultiplier;
                scaleY = Mathf.Clamp(scaleY, scaleYMin, scaleYMax);
            }
        }
        
        transform.SetLocalScaleY(scaleY);
    }

    void OnVoiceStarts(AudioSource audioSource)
    {
        this.audioSource = audioSource;
        clipData = new float[this.audioSource.clip.samples];
    }

    void OnVoiceEnds()
    {
        this.audioSource = null;
    }
}
```

Some notes on above:

- I've played with various values for updateSeconds and also tried a RepeatInvoke, to no avail.
- I've played with various threshold values (the goal is to have the lips be closed on near-silence), and also removed the threshold check completely, but it won't help.
- The code tries to automatically determine typical min and max loudness (so as to show the mouth at fullest range independent of the specific audio).
- I've already set the audioSource priority to 0, the highest.
- The contents of the audioClip isn't knowable in advance as it's live-written by the GPT-3 AI based on what the user asked.

Comment: First of all you iterate all `audioSource.timeSamples` into one value .. wouldn't you rather want to use a fixed amount and take the average of let's say the last 10 samples?

Comment: @derHugo So `audioSource.timeSamples` according to the docs is used "to read current playback time or to seek to a new playback time in samples", and I'm passing it as second parameter `offsetSamples`, which according to the docs is "to start the read from a specific position in the clip". This in combination, and also how I see this used elsewhere, would mean the current time, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah yes sorry it is indeed the offset my bad. Still I would expect you to take the average of given sample frames and not the sum ..

Comment: Your follow-up just put me in the right direction, thanks! While dividing the samples to average won't help here (but it's good practice, so I will!), the culprit was that I had originally set the array `clipData[] = new float[this.audioSource.clip.samples];` -- this caused it, when passing to the getData function with timeSamples later, to always read the full amount of samples from that tick till the end (instead of just looking ahead a relevant portion -- in my case, the amount was 137966 instead of a reasonable one like 512)! So I just need to do e.g. `new float[512]` and it works great!

Comment: @derHugo I posted an answer with credit for your help putting this in the right direction, thanks again!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen great! That's how I like Stackoverflow the most, be a help for others to understand and finally figure it out themselves ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With credit to derHugo for helping, the following solves it by providing a constant (and smaller) array size to `clipData`, like 512, so that it won't grab too much during `getData`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class SyncMouthToAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float scaleYMin = 0.01f;
    const float scaleYMax = 0.05f;

    TextToSpeechVoice voice = null;

    AudioSource audioSource = null;
    float[] clipData = null;
    int samplesPerCheck = 0;

    float detectedLoudnessMin = Mathf.Infinity;
    float detectedLoudnessMax = 0f;

    const float checkEveryNSeconds = 0.05f;

    void Start()
    {
        voice = GetComponentInParent<TextToSpeechVoice>();
        voice.onStarts += OnVoiceStarts;
        voice.onEnds += OnVoiceEnds;
    }

    void CheckLoudness()
    {
        float loudness = 0f;
        if (audioSource != null && audioSource.isPlaying && audioSource.timeSamples > 0)
        {
            int offset = clipData.Length / 2;
            int startSample = (int) Mathf.Clamp(
                audioSource.timeSamples - offset, 0, audioSource.clip.samples - offset);
            audioSource.clip.GetData(clipData, startSample);
            loudness = clipData.Select(x => Mathf.Abs(x)).Average();

            if      (loudness < detectedLoudnessMin) { detectedLoudnessMin = loudness; }
            else if (loudness > detectedLoudnessMax) { detectedLoudnessMax = loudness; }
        }

        SetScaleByLoudness(loudness);
    }

    void SetScaleByLoudness(float loudness)
    {
        const float visibilityMultiplier = 15f;
        float scaleY = scaleYMin;

        if (loudness > 0f && detectedLoudnessMin < Mathf.Infinity &&
            detectedLoudnessMax > 0f && detectedLoudnessMin < detectedLoudnessMax)
        {
            float range = detectedLoudnessMax - detectedLoudnessMin;

            float scaleRange = scaleYMax - scaleYMin;
            float loudnessRange = detectedLoudnessMax - detectedLoudnessMin;

            float scaleToLoudnessRatio = scaleRange / loudnessRange;

            scaleY = scaleYMin + (loudness - detectedLoudnessMin) *
                scaleToLoudnessRatio * scaleYMax * visibilityMultiplier;
            scaleY = Mathf.Clamp(scaleY, scaleYMin, scaleYMax);
        }
        
        transform.SetLocalScaleY(scaleY);
    }

    void OnVoiceStarts(AudioSource audioSource)
    {
        this.audioSource = audioSource;

        float numberOfChecks = audioSource.clip.length / checkEveryNSeconds;
        samplesPerCheck = (int) Mathf.Round(audioSource.clip.samples / numberOfChecks);

        clipData = new float[samplesPerCheck];

        CancelInvoke();
        InvokeRepeating("CheckLoudness", checkEveryNSeconds * 0.5f, checkEveryNSeconds);
    }

    void OnVoiceEnds()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        this.audioSource = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could now even play around a bit with which range of samples you want to work ... you could e.g. use the `updateTime` and use exactly the amount of samples fitting into it ... or you could try and shift the range like e.g. `audioSource.clip.GetData(clipData, audioSource.timeSamples - clipData.Length / 2);` in order to take half past half future samples etc

Comment: Right that makes sense! I'll try that and update here if it works out. (I also want to see if there's low-hanging phoneme fruits.)

Comment: @derHugo I've now switched to your suggestion. Works great. I've also switched the averaging of the absolutes to Linq for readability, not necessarily a needed change though.

Comment: Setting the mouth width by pseudo-phonemes -- making it less wide when the letter 'o' is timed to appear -- works surprisingly well and convincing. Not sure if I should add that code here as it might exceed the scope of the question. But if anyone is interested, you just set the interval length to the amount of letters in the speech text, then during each check adjust scaleX by appearance of char 'o'. (Not every 'o' should result in an O-shaped mouth in reality -- e.g. "something" vs "road" -- but to start being useful, this algorithm just needs to be superior to no phoneme checking at all.)